# Proper use of argparse when a tool has subcommands

Tags: python, argparse

I'm looking for a simple solution to have 2 of 3 'subcommands' in a python tool that each require their own flags (if any).

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='tester')
    parser.add_argument('args', nargs='*')
    argsDict = vars(parser.parse_args())
    cmd = argsDict['args'][0]
    if cmd == "simple":
        # no flags required on
        # test.py simple
        print("cmd = %s"%cmd)
    elif cmd == "complex":
        # flags required on
        # test.py complex
        # require -l
        parser.add_argument('args', nargs='*')
        parser.add_argument('-l','--level', help='set complexity', required=True)
        print("cmd = %s"%cmd)
        argsDict = vars(parser.parse_args())
        print(argsDict)
```

the code above reflects my current setup.
However this returns:

```
$ python ./test.py complex -l 4
usage: test.py [-h] [args [args ...]]
test.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -l 4
```

any hints on how to implement this?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='tester')
    #parser.add_argument('args', nargs='+')
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='cmd', help='sub-command help')

    parser_simple = subparsers.add_parser('simple', help="this is the help for the simple subcommand")

    parser_complex = subparsers.add_parser('complex', help="this is the help for the complex subcommand")
    parser_complex.add_argument('-l','--level', help='set complexity', required=True)

    argsDict = vars(parser.parse_args())
    cmd = argsDict['cmd']
    if cmd == "simple":
        # no flags required on
        # test.py simple
        print("cmd = %s"%cmd)
    elif cmd == "complex":
        # flags required on
        # test.py complex
        # require -l
        print("cmd = %s"%cmd)
        print(argsDict)
    else:
        print("fail")
```

is the updated codesample that performs as expected.
Many thanks to @jonrsharpe for the hint I overlooked.